# how to invoke Result Set method in java?

Tags: java, method-invocation

ResultSet data_result = dao.getDetails();

```
Method resultset_method;

resultset_method = data_result.getClass().getMethod("getInt", Integer.class);
```

it is giving error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(java.lang.Integer)
```

Comment: Why not calling the `getInt` method directly on the `ResultSet` object?

Comment: to give an example i have given like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ResultSet`'s `getInt` method has two overloads, one that takes an `int` for the index and one that takes a `String` for a column name. You're attempting to retrieve a `getInt()` method, which indeed does not exist.

You need to supply the types that the method takes - eg, if you were going by name,

```
resultset_method = data_result.getClass().getMethod("getInt", String.class);
```

Comment: still it is not working:: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getInt()

Comment: Same error? Can you update your answer including your new code?

Comment: resultset_method = data_result.getClass().getMethod("getInt", Integer.class); and the error is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getInt(java.lang.Integer)

Comment: @MaheshPVM No, edit the question.

Comment: Guess you have to use `Integer.TYPE` , not `Integer.class`.

Comment: Yes !! it is working Thanks to Evan Knowles and  Gyro Gearless